# Sending JSON data through formData - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I am sending videos to a server in my application.  But the user is also entering information about the video.  My question is how can I attach that to my `formData` to be sent to my server as a JSON?

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mySite.com/dev/iphone/"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"downloadFileChallange.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
{
 [formData appendPartWithFileData:webData name:@"file" fileName:newUsername mimeType:@"video/quicktime"]; <-- here is where I want to attach the information
}];
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Add them as parameters to the `request`?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: `parameters = @{ @"loginName": self.loginName.text };`

Comment: @bgfriend0 oh shoot, I did not think of that ahaha!  If you put that awnser I will give it to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary and pass your parameters into the `request` object, e.g.,:

```
parameters = @{ @"loginName": self.loginName.text };
```